# Redis remote connection refuse

Tags: redis

I have a 3 nodes Redis primary/secondary setup. Secondary nodes are configured as a replicaof. My setup has been running great for couple of years and last week for some reasons my servers got restarted and our apps could not connect to the primary server. I could ssh to the box and use redis-cli but cannot connect to the server using redis-cli from different machine/remote. I had to change the bind property from `bind 127.0.0.1 my.server.ip to bind 0.0.0.0.` Can someone please help me figure out why ? Thanks!! My primary redis.conf looks like

```
bind 127.0.0.1 my.server.ip
requirepass foobared
protected-mode yes
```

Replicas redis.conf

```
bind 127.0.0.1 
replicaof my.server.ip 6379
masterauth foobared
protected-mode yes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected-mode yes
```

Disallows connections from public IPs and is detailed https://redis.io/topics/security

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still trying to figure out why it was working before.

Comment: protected-mode can also be set on the command line ```redis-cli config set protected-mode yes``` so it's possible it got set but not written to the configuration file (guilty of this myself during emergencies)